# jQuery returns my html page after success call

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have an admin panel with navbar and modal form. When I submit the modal form I get back my Html file + the response code from my PHP.

```js
$("#frmcrtNewExam").on("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = new FormData(this);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: process.php,
    data: form,
    contentType: false,
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" }, // dataType: 'json', success: function(response) { console.log(response); }
  });
  return false;
});
```

## Response log

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Favicons -->
<!--Google Fonts-->
<!-- ======= Header ======= -->
<div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
   <a href="index.html" class="logo d-flex align-items-center">
   <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="">
   </a>
   <i class="bi bi-list toggle-sidebar-btn"></i>
</div>
<!--End Logo-- >
   < !--End Header-- >  < !-- ======= Sidebar ======= -->
<aside id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
   <ul class="sidebar-nav" id="sidebar-nav">
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link " href="index.php">
      <i class="bi bi-grid"></i>
      <span>Dashboard</span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <!-- End Dashboard Nav -->
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link collapsed" data-bs-target="#components-nav" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#">
      <i class="bi bi-menu-button-wide"></i><span>Students</span><i class="bi bi-chevron-down ms-auto"></i>
      </a>
      <ul id="components-nav" class="nav-content collapse " data-bs-parent="#sidebar-nav">
         <li>
            <a href="components-alerts.html">
            <i class="bi bi-circle"></i><span>Register</span>
            </a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="forms-elements.html">
            <i class="bi bi-circle"></i><span>Add New</span>
            </a>
         </li>
         </li>
         <!-- End Forms Nav -->
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link collapsed" data-bs-target="#tables-nav" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-layout-text-window-reverse"></i><span>Setup</span><i class="bi bi-chevron-down ms-auto"></i>
            </a>
         </li>
      </ul>
</aside>
<!--End Sidebar-- >
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, i remove the html include header in the php file and everything works fine.